# How to bring a multi-datatable with pagination,sorting,filtering in single component file in angular 7

Tags: datatables, angular-material, angular7, paginator

I am trying to get multi-table with pagination, sorting, filtering in a single component.

I can get pagination for one table, unable to get pagination for multiple tables in a single component.

I also received the data from all tables. I am receiving the data from the backend so it takes a few seconds.

I Couldn't find any multi-data table example in angular7 material

This is my code

````
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'id', 'products_count', 'domain'];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  public NONAR_ELEMENT_DATA: NonARElement[];
  displayedColumns1: string[] = ['pro_id', 'name', 'd_image'];
  public dataSource1 = new MatTableDataSource<NonARElement>(this.NONAR_ELEMENT_DATA);


  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('paginator1', { read: MatPaginator }) paginator1: MatPaginator;



_setDataSource(indexNumber) {
    console.log("indexNumber", indexNumber)
    setTimeout(() => {
      switch (indexNumber) {
        case 0:
          !this.dataSource1.paginator ? this.dataSource1.paginator = this.paginator1 : null;
          console.log("this.dataSource-NON AR.paginator", this.dataSource.paginator)

          break;
        case 1:
          !this.dataSource.paginator ? this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator : null;
          console.log("this.dataSource-Storelist.paginator", this.dataSource1.paginator)
      }
    },1000);
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your html page. Have you used this #name in your paginator?

```
<mat-paginator #paginator length="100"
               pageSize="20"
               pageSizeOptions="[10,20,30]"
               (page)="pageChanged($event)">
</mat-paginator>

@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```